# Finite automata, Pushdown automata and Turing machine examples

Tags: finite-automata, turing-machines, pushdown-automaton

I'm looking for some good source of Finite automata, pushdown automata and Turing machine tasks examples (for solving manually, by hand).

I was searching around but didn't find nothing special so I'm wondering if someone's got some good examples. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet might be to get a book on the subject, such as [Introduction to the Theory of Computation, Third Edition](http://www.cengage.com/search/productOverview.do?Ntt=sipser%7C%7C991938321204392568016032450701059771599&N=0&Ntk=all%7C%7CP_EPI) by Michael Sipser, and then work through the exercises.

For a collection of problem sets on automata, along with solutions, check out [Stanford's introductory course in the theory of computation](http://www.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1134/).  Problem Sets 5, 6, and 7 directly talk about automata (finite, pushdown, and Turing machines), along with equivalent representations (regular expressions and context-free grammars).

Hope this helps!