# Deterministic Finite Automaton vs Deterministic Pushdown Automaton

Tags: language-agnostic, dfa, pushdown-automaton

I was wondering if somebody could give me a simple explanation of the relationship between these two terms, as I am very confused by the terminology.

Comment: A DFA is a "state" machine, whereas a PDA is a "stack" machine.  What aspects of the terminology are confusing you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164479/finite-automata-pushdown-automata-and-turing-machine-examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Deterministic [Pushdown Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) (DPDA) is a [Deterministic Finite Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_pushdown_automaton) (DFA) that also has access to a [Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29), which is a Last In, First Out (LIFO) data structure.

Having access to a form of memory allows a DPDA to recognize a greater variety of strings than a DFA.  For example, given a language with symbols A and B, a DFA could be constructed to recognize AB, AABB, AAABBB, but no DFA can be constructed to recognize A^nB^n for all n, whereas that is easily done with a DPDA that works as follows:

1. Enter start state.
2. Push `$` to the stack.
3. Read letter from string.

   - if B, go to a terminal non-accept state.
   - if A, push A on the stack, and go to state 4.
4. Read a letter from string

   - if A, push A on the stack and stay in this state
   - if B, pop the top value from the stack.

     - If the popped value is A, go to state 5.
     - If the popped value is $, go to a terminal non-accept state.
5. Read a letter from string

   - if B, pop the top value from the stack.

     - If the popped value is A, stay in this state.
     - If the popped value is $, go to a terminal non-accept state.
   - if we read the end of the string, pop the top value from the stack

     - If the popped value is $, go to the accept state
     - If the popped value is A, go to a terminal non-accept state.
   - if we read anything else from the string, go to a terminal non-accept state.

PDAs recognize [context-free languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language), with DPDAs recognizing only the deterministic subset of context-free languages.  They are more powerful than DFAs in terms of the number of languages they can recognize, but less powerful than [Turing Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine)